# MySQL Query not returning a row value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know why this query won't return a value because when I copy the "echoed" portion into phpmyadmin I do get a record returning:

```
echo $_GET["cname"];

// Query template
$sql =  'SELECT C.cid FROM `Contact` C WHERE C.email="'.$_GET["cname"].'"';
echo $sql;

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result( $res_cid);

echo $res_cid;
```

`$res_cid` is apparently 0, but I don't know why because when I paste that query manually into phpmyadmin I do get a value... So why doesn't it return anything?

Comment: can you try to remove quote near contact ? and i dont know what you plan to do but your code is totally unsecure, you'd better use bindparam with PDO

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I agree with @ThomasP1988 . Putting user input directly into the query string defeats the purpose of prepared statement.

Comment: Guys, this is a project for one of my classes, so I am not concerned with security because once my application works then it is never used agian.

Comment: So you're taking a class, but not interested in learning the proper way to program? Why are you taking the class then?

Comment: @Barmar the class doesn't technically teach anything about SQL except basics. It is an entry level class. Even though I know better way to code it is not efficient for me to spend extra time or effort coding something that will not get me extra marks or something not even graded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments - you should make sure your code is secured. You better use the [bindparam](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for that.

As for your question - after you execute your query and [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) you should also [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) to get the actual value from the database, based on your query:

```php
// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result( $res_cid);

// Fetch to get the actual result
$stmt->fetch();
echo $res_cid;
```